# VBA to export specific sheets based on cell values to PDF

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to output certain ranges on various sheets to pdf based on whether Cells E22,E24,E26,E28,E30 On "Front Sheet" = 1 and it would output sheets "Front Sheet,Dimension Report,Drawing,Dimension Printout, HFQ Report,Hardness Data", so if E22 =1 it would output "Front Sheet" and if E22 = 1 then it would output "Dimension Report" but if E26 did not = 1 then it would igonre that page but still output the rest

On my current code I get a runtime error 9. and im not sure how to resolve this issue

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Const cESheets As String = "Front Sheet,Dimension Report,Drawing,Dimension Printout, HFQ Report,Hardness Data"
    Const cSheet As String = "Front Sheet"
    Const cRange As String = "E22,E24,E26,E28,E30"
    Const cCrit As Long = 1

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim Cell As Range
    Dim vntS As Variant
    Dim iFound As Long

    ' **********************************
    ' Copy Sheets to New workbook.
    ' **********************************

    
    vntS = Split(cESheets, ",")

    
    With ThisWorkbook
        For Each Cell In .Worksheets(cSheet).Range(cRange)
            If Cell.Value = cCrit Then
                iFound = iFound + 1
                If iFound = 1 Then
                    .Sheets(Trim(vntS(iFound - 1))).Copy
                    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
                  Else
                    .Sheets(Trim(vntS(iFound - 1))).Copy _
                            After:=wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count)
                End If
              'Else
            End If
        Next
    End With

    ' **********************************
    ' Export New Workbook to PDF
    ' **********************************

    If iFound = 0 Then Exit Sub


    With wb
        .ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:="Exported.pdf", _
                Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
                IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True
        .Close False
    End With

End Sub
```

I am getting the runtime error 9 at:

```
Else
                    .Sheets(Trim(vntS(iFound - 1))).Copy _
                            After:=wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count)
```

I am fairly new to VBA so anyway help is appreciated.

Comment: That means the result of `Trim(vntS(iFound - 1))` is not a valid sheet name in that workbook.

Comment: Any advice on how to resolve the issue?

Comment: `Debug.Print Trim(vntS(iFound - 1))` first to figure out which sheet name you're dealing with... then compare spelling / spacing to the sheet name in the workbook.

Comment: Yeah that resolved that issue, now I have an issue where each cell doesn't correspond to the sheet, so if I have E30 = 1 and the other = 0 but it'll will only output the first sheet instead of the last, so it looks as though it just checks to see if any of the cells has a 1 and if it does it will just output the first sheet, so if it finds 3 cells that have a 1 it will output the first 3 sheets, instead of the sheets that correspond to the cell

Answer (score 0):

### Export to PDF Based on Cell Value

- Adjust the values in the constants section.
- Unless no cell contains criteria value (nothing will happen), the first worksheet and the worksheets designated by each cell where the criteria value was found, will be copied.

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Const cESheets As String = "Sheet1,Sheet2,Sheet3,Sheet4,Sheet5,Sheet6"
    Const cSheet As String = "Sheet1"
    Const cRange As String = "E22,E24,E26,E28,E30"
    Const cCrit As Long = 1

    Dim dwb As Workbook
    Dim sws As Worksheet
    Dim Cell As Range
    Dim vntS() As String
    Dim iFound As Long

    
    vntS = Split(cESheets, ",")
    
    Set sws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Trim(vntS(0)))
    
    ' Sum is incorrect, and CountIf doesn't work on non-contiguous cells.
    For Each Cell In sws.Range(cRange).Cells
        If Cell.Value = cCrit Then
            iFound = 1
            Exit For
        End If
    Next Cell
    If iFound = 0 Then Exit Sub
    
    ' **********************************
    ' Copy Sheets to New workbook.
    ' **********************************
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    sws.Copy
    Set dwb = ActiveWorkbook
    iFound = 0
    
    For Each Cell In sws.Range(cRange).Cells
        iFound = iFound + 1
        If Cell.Value = cCrit Then
            sws.Parent.Worksheets(Trim(vntS(iFound))).Copy _
                After:=dwb.Sheets(dwb.Sheets.Count)
        End If
    Next

    ' **********************************
    ' Export New Workbook to PDF
    ' **********************************

     With dwb
        .ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:="Exported.pdf", _
                Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
                IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True
        .Close False
    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```